# Full screen and zoom to page width in Preview or Skim on Mac

Tags: pdf, adobe-reader, preview, fullscreen, zoom

One of the features that seem to be lacking on Preview is an **automatic zoom to page width** during full screen view. This is very helpful when reading user manuals and other long texts.

I would normally right-click, then **Zoom In** repeatedly; whereas for Adobe Reader (on Windows), I would just Ctrl+Wheel Up.

I wish Preview would have been easier. Or did I just overlook how to do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I got it now. I can right-click on the page, then select Single Page Continuous. With this setting, choosing Zoom to Fit Window will zoom to the page width.

Comment: Unfortunately, in full-screen mode, choosing "Single Page Continuous" for one page reverts to "Single Page" the moment one advances the page. I'm baffled by this; isn't the whole point of "continuous" to control the behavior *between* pages?

Comment: for Skim: The "Zoom to fit" option is under the `PDF` menu, not the `View` menu as I would have expected. Shortcut key is `Command-_` (`Apple-_`)

Answer (score 3):

Though this unfortunately isn’t available in full-screen view, you can choose **View** > **Automatically Resize** in non-full-screen view. Then click the green “+” button to make the window fill up the screen.

Answer (score 2):

This issue baffled me for quite a long time too. All I wanted to do was view PDFs full screen as in "absolutely full screen" and be able to scroll between pages.

The trick here is to right click and select "Single Page Continuous".

Yes, it will go back to Single Page again, but now you'll have your PDF full screen. To scroll between pages, use the three-finger touch, not the two-finger one.

Answer (score -1):

Saamrat is right... go to full screen with green button top left corner, dont use View menu + Enter full screen,

then right click or control+click and click "Single Page Continuous".

works on Catalina in 2023... (Acrobat Pro 2010 got discontinued so nowadays forced to use Mac's Viewer for pdfs)

Comment: Hello, I don't think your answer adds much to this question compared to the other one. You only added slightly more accurate instruction with completely unnecessary caps lock.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Please don't post "me too" as an answer. You can show your appreciation for another user's answer by upvoting it, once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation). Please take the time to take the [Tour](https://superuser.com/tour) and read the [Help pages](https://superuser.com/help).